# Formatting chord diagram based on matrix-input

Tags: r, matrix, plot, chord-diagram

## Current Situation

In my previous question [Data frame into a symmetric matrix while keeping all row and column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51629393/data-frame-into-a-symmetric-matrix-while-keeping-all-row-and-column), I ended up with a symmetric matrix, which I'd like to transform into a formatted chord diagram like this:

```
library(edgebundleR)

# data
x <- structure(c(1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0), 
               .Dim = c(3L,5L), 
               .Dimnames = list(c("a.X", "a.Y", "b.Z"), c("a.A", "a.B", "a.C", "b.D", "b.E")))
x <- as.matrix(x)
x <- rbind(cbind(diag(nrow(x)), x), cbind(t(x), diag(ncol(x))))
colnames(x) <- rownames(x)

# plot
edgebundle(x)

# plot with basic formatting using the arguments of edgebundle()
edgebundle(x,
           tension=1,
           fontsize = 12,
           cutoff = 0, 
           width = 1000,
           padding = 230,
           nodesize = c(5, 30))
```

## The Problem

However, similar to [Color edges and vertex in chord diagram using edgebundle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42509593/color-edges-and-vertex-in-chord-diagram-using-edgebundle) I'd like to go a step further and change the colors of the lines and nodes (by default and during mouseover), which is possible when using an igraph-object as shown in [Network chord diagram woes in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30708674/network-chord-diagram-woes-in-r/32260962#32260962) and in the [documentation](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/edgebundleR/README.html).

After having read the [PDF-documentation](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/edgebundleR/edgebundleR.pdf) of `edgebundleR` I suppose this isn't currently part of the functionality of the package, but it would also be nice to...

- include grouping-labels based on the groups `c("a.", "b.")`
- change the fontface of the text
- use different colors for lines that point to different groups when a
  category is selected (as in this [example](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/7607999) for input and output)
- add a title to the plot that stays in place when the plot is rotated

## My Questions

1. Is it possible to color the lines and nodes per group when using a
   matrix instead of an igraph-object, preferentially using color-codes
   (rgb, hex), and if yes, how?
2. Despite not being included in the basic functionality, is there a
   way to do the advanced formatting from above? (without having to rewrite or extend the package to a huge degree, of course)

Thank you for your suggestions!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the meantime I figured out a way how to change the color of the overall plot (including the text, lines and nodes). I'd like to share it here in order to spare someone with similar ambitions a few hours of research.

## 1. Changing the Colors of the Chord-Diagram

It works by converting the matrix into an igraph-object and setting the color through the vertices `V()` function. Colors can be set per group, vertex per vertex using recycling or as a whole when only using one color.

```
library(igraph)   

# transform into igraph-object
y <- graph_from_adjacency_matrix(as.matrix(x, "adjacency"), mode = "undirected")

# setting colors

# Per group
V(y)[which(substring(colnames(x),0,1) %in% "a")]$color <- "green"
V(y)[which(substring(colnames(x),0,1) %in% "b")]$color <- "red"
edgebundle(y)

# vertex per vertex
V(y)$color <- c("green", "red") 
edgebundle(y)

# as a whole
V(y)$color <- "#a98561" # hex-codes are supported
edgebundle(y)
```

## 2. Advanced Formatting

After all, igraph comes with functions for defining a title `y$main`, changing the colors of the lines, i.e. edges, by use of the `E()` function `E(y)$color`, changing the font of the labels `V(y)$label.family` and other tools for better formatting (see: [manual](http://igraph.org/r/doc/plot.common.html)). Unfortunately, these things aren't supported by the `edgebundleR` package. They're just having no effect when being used. Below, I provided a brief example to get a feeling for these settings showing the differences between `edgebundle()` and `plot.igraph()`.

```
# settings
y$main <- "Title"
E(y)$color <- "red"
V(y)$label.family <- "Arial"

# see plots
plot.igraph(y)
edgebundle(y)
```

It seems that changing the color of the lines, i.e. edges, during mouseover isn't possible without extending the package. `edgebundle()`'s default settings point to blue for the standard lines and to red during mouseover. These values get replaced with the same color once specified. There's currently no option to define different colors for standard lines and during mouseover.

There's also no possibilty to add grouping labels to the text-groups.

## Prospect

If someone is able to solve these issues or if `edgebundleR` receives an update containing new functionalities you're welcome to extend this answer.